# Store and retrieve html from sql server 2008 and display using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I am trying to store HTML and hyperlinks in my SQL server 2008 database. I want to also be able to display the hyperlinks and render the HTML accordingly. I am trying to do this in ASP.NET MVC, so I tried using the HTTPUtility.HtmlEncode() method, but didn't really store it the way I wanted. So can anyone please guide me through the steps I need to take to achieve this.

Comment: Silly game.  The only way to win is not to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be the MVC way in that you have a PartialView for each link.  Then all you need to do is itterate through your collection of links and render a Partial View accordingly.

**edit**

When i say collection of links, i mean a collection of non html links.  Just the addresses.

In your controller you might have;

```
List<string> links = fillList();
Return View(links);
```

Then in your view;

```
foreach(string item in Model.links)
  Html.Renderpartial("htmlLink", item);
```